# Optimize gradle for spring-xd project with transient scala dependency

Tags: scala, gradle, spring-xd

I am working on a project that contains a series of module subprojects for spring XD which happen to have a transient dependency on a non-module subproject that happens to use Scala:

```
ext {
  springXdVersion = '1.1.0.RELEASE'
  moduleProjects  = subprojects.findAll { project -> project.path.startsWith(':modules.')}
  javaProjects    = subprojects - (moduleProjects + nonJavaProjects)
}

configure(moduleProjects) { moduleProject ->
  apply plugin: 'spring-xd-module'
}

project('core-dependency') {
  apply plugin: 'scala'
  // configuration/dependencies
}

project('modules.source.example') {
  dependencies {
    provided(":core-dependency")
  }
}

// More modules bearing resemblance to modules.source.example
```

Core-dependency is ultimately set up to be in the classpath of our xd-container, and is provided to the modules at runtime in this manner.

Unfortunately, it seems that for each module that uses it, the core-dependency gets recompiled (which is particularly expensive since it includes a scala compile, too).  This causes builds to run north of 30 minutes, which I'd like to improve upon.  Is there a way to bring down the build time?  Ideally, I'd like to not have to recompile core-dependency, but I'm not sure how to approach accomplishing this, considering that bootRepackage seems to be responsible for triggering it for each module.  I have also tried other tricks, such as parallelism, but doing this has only managed to freeze my system so far.  I am using gradle 2.1.

I should note that a gradle profile report indicates that for each module, most of the time sunk is in the configureModule step, which, according to the spring-xd repo, looks like this:

```
project.task('configureModule') << {
            project.configurations.provided.resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies.each {
                excludeTransitiveDependencies(project, it)
            }
        }
```

Comment: I may have a working solution: I created a configuration named core, and set compile to extend from it (which means it will compile that, along with the provided scope).  Since my core-dependency would no longer be provided, it won't be involved with the configureModule task's excludeTransitiveDependencies.  This cut my build from 35 minutes, to 2 minutes.  I'm testing my artifacts now for functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately, that had the side effect of packaging my module fatjars with that core-dependency and its dependencies, defeating the purpose.

Comment: `configurations.exported.exclude module: 'core-dependency'` was able to fix the issue in that last comment.  The exported configuration is introduced by the spring-xd-modules plugin, which is used to determine what goes in the fatjar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the configureModule step, all projects are evaluated for transitive provided dependencies, which core-dependency was.  The slowdown was caused by the sheer number of dependencies that core-dependency relies on, and consquently requires scanning.  Since we want to avoid having core-dependency scanned by configureModule because it is too time-expensive, and we know it needs to be excluded from module fatjars, the appropriate course of action is to remove core-dependency from the provided configuration, and simply exclude it from the fat jar ourselves.

To accomplish this, the gradle build script is modified as follows:

```
ext {
  springXdVersion = '1.1.0.RELEASE'
  moduleProjects  = subprojects.findAll { project -> project.path.startsWith(':modules.')}
  javaProjects    = subprojects - (moduleProjects + nonJavaProjects)
}

configure(moduleProjects) { moduleProject ->
  apply plugin: 'spring-xd-module'

  configurations{
    core
    compile.extendsFrom(core)
  }

configurations.exported.exclude module: 'core-dependency'
}

project('core-dependency') {
  apply plugin: 'scala'
  // configuration/dependencies
}

project('modules.source.example') {
  dependencies {
    core project(":core-dependency")
  }
}

// More modules bearing resemblance to modules.source.example
```

The "core" configuration is essentially a second "provided" configuration, which will not get picked up by the configureModule task, avoiding the time wasting evaluation upon it.  It is also excluded from the "exported" configuration, whose contents determines what goes into the fat jar that bootRepackage builds.

Answer (score 0):

The scala dependency comes from `Spark streaming` integration in SpringXD. We are working on removing the spark dependency on `spring-xd-dirt` and have it served from module:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-2857

What specific non-module subproject you depend on? If it is `spring-xd-module`, then you can try 1.2.0.M1 where we have moved the spark dependency from `spring-xd-module` to `spring-xd-dirt`.

Comment: The subproject is an internal dependency; a subproject consisting of internally developed tools commonly used between our modules.